# How to use Calibri Font as default while developing crystal report?

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports

Im uisng `Calibrilight` font in my crystal report.But whenever i create a textdocument the default font is `Arial`.

Is there any way to set `Calibrilight` as default font instead of `Arial` in crystal report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **Default Font** for every fields, text objects, etc., as you wish
Please refer the following Steps.
Go to **File** -> **Options** in your Crystal Reports Editor.
[image]

In Options, select **Fonts** tab. So you will get the following items to set your default fonts
[image]

Select **Text Objects** (or any other item) for which you want to set your default font.
You will be prompted with Fonts Dialog to select your **Default Fonts** and **Styles**
[image]
Hope this helps !
Leave comments if u need anything more.

Comment: Im using crystal report version 13.0.2000.0.In this i got to the Font Tab by the following method.CrystalReport Menu >> Design >> Default Settings >> Font.

Comment: Great. Since you didnt mention the version, I just answered with Crystal Reports XI.